# TFS build 2008 :error in building

Tags: windows-7

i am getting error while making the build. the error is........

Tf215085: An error occurred while connecting to agent\tushar_yeole\jj: TF209009: The account NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM is not authorized to communicate with team foundation server http://ws001373:8080 verify that the account is member of build services

-tushar_yeole is my project name
-jj build agent
-http://ws001373:8080 -this is server 
-I am building on my own machine
- I have installed build service on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an error when TFS updates the statement of the build agent. Could you try to build on another build agent or  update the statement of the build agent from Team Explore to see whether this issue will occur?